# Rails factory_girl create_list builds the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
factory :product, class: Product do
  name        Faker::Commerce.product_name
  description Faker::Lorem.paragraph
  price       Faker::Number.number(3)
end
```

When I call FactoryGirl.create_list(:product, 3) it inserts in the database the same product with only a different id. I would like to have a different name, description and price for each of the products.

Do you guys know a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`name`, `description`, and `price` are being treated as static attributes; this means the value is calculated once (when the factories are loaded) and will never change (and the reason why the data is the same for each instance of `Product`.

Instead, wrap the values in a block:

```
    factory :product, class: Product do
      name        { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
      description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
      price       { Faker::Number.number(3) }
    end
```

Every time the factory is run, this block gets executed - and in the case of Faker, that means it'll generate a new value.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Great answer, I should've realized that if I wrap it in a block it would have been executed for each product. Thanks!